# Set data of view model which is a custom object list of base objects

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

EDIT:

To add a little more background:
I developed a client app which one could use to define candlestick patterns to automatically analyse stocks or a stockmarket. Now i came up with the idea that it would be much better to migrate it to a web application using ASP.net since the client app is C#. Well, i thought i already have all the models, so i "only" have to build the views and controllers and done...

Anyway, when i was developing the client app i created some kind of common classes which are part of a framework i use all the time. One of these base classes for example is CBaseObjectList. Its member is a List<> of CBaseObecject. The class encapsulates serveral functions like add, delete, sorting, initialsing from a database, write to database etc...

What i basically like to do is to use these classes for displaying, adding, deleting, changeing data in the view.

This is what i do:

In the controller i initialise the list from database and call the view with the list as parameter:

```
public ActionResult ShowCandleStickPattern()
{

   // initialise list from data
   CCandleStickPattern_Lst patternLst  = new CCandleStickPattern_Lst();
   string SQL                          = "SELECT * FROM tab_candlestick_pattern";
   CDBCon_MySql pDBCon                 = CRM_Handler.GetDBCon();
   patternLst.InitListFromDB           (pDBCon, SQL, new CCandleStick_Pattern());

   return View(patternLst);
 }
```

The values of the list are correctly displayed in the view. But when i change some of the displayed fields and submit, the list is always null in the [HttpPost] controller function.

```
  [HttpPost]
  public string ShowCandleStickPattern(CCandleStickPattern_Lst lst)
  {
    return lst.GetItemsCount().ToString();
  }
```

The CCandleStickPattern_Lst looks as follows:

```
public class CCandleStickPattern_Lst : CBaseObjectList 
{

  public List<CBaseObject> MyList
  {
    get { return m_MyList; }
  }
}
```

The CBaseObjectList looks like this:

```
public class CBaseObjectList : CBaseObject
{
  protected List<CBaseObject> m_MyList = null;
}

protected CBaseObject AddNewItem_Base(CBaseObject pBaseObj) {...}
...
```

The view:

```
@model CCandleStickPattern_Lst

<h1>List of Candlestick pattern</h1>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowCandleStickPattern", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table border="1" cellpadding="6">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.GetItemsCount(); i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => ((CCandleStick_Pattern)model.MyList[i]).DB_ID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => ((CCandleStick_Pattern)model.MyList[i]).Pattern_Name);
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => ((CCandleStick_Pattern)model.MyList[i]).Pattern_Description);
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => ((CCandleStick_Pattern)model.MyList[i]).PatternType);
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

I got this working when i add a new member and property to `CCandleStickPattern_Lst`, use that instead of the list of baseobjects of the baseclass and access `CandlePatternLst` instead of `MyList` in the view.

```
private List<CCandleStick_Pattern> m_CandlePatternLst;
public List<CCandleStick_Pattern> CandlePatternLst {
    get return m_CandlePatternLst;
}
```

So it seems like there is something i am missing with the list of baseobjects? How can I make this work?

Comment: Could you be more clear about what you expect to happen, what isn't happening and an example of failure.

Comment: Your properties need setters in order for the `DefaultModelBinder` to **set** their values - `public List<CBaseObject> MyList { get; set; }`

Comment: But using `(CCandleStick_Pattern)` makes no sense - when you submit, your controls will bind to the base class, not the derived class

Comment: What i expect to happen: When i change the listed data in the view and submit, i receive the data in the controller. But the list i receive in the controller is null.

Comment: @StephenMuecke how do i bind it then to the derived class, without changeing CCandleStickPattern_Lst and CBaseObjectList ?

Comment: You cannot. First, it does not matter what is displayed - what matters if the `name` attributes of your form controls and if you look at your html, you will see multiple elements with `name="DB_ID"` but they would need to be `name="MyList[0].DB_ID"`, `name="MyList[1].DB_ID"` etc. Second, you cannot bind to fields - you must use properties with getters and setters. Third, the DefaultModelBinder` initializes your model and then sets its properties so it initializes `List<CBaseObject>`, not `List<CCandleStick_Pattern>`.

Comment: There is too much in your code which makes no sense, but you need to start by creating a view model with properties that need in the view and strongly bind to those properties (no casting) and then post back to that view model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your answers. I edited the original question to add a little more background. Maybe this can lead to far, but could you explain what you exactly mean is sensless code? Second, when i look at the html i don´t see name="DB_ID", but i see MyList[0].DB_ID. I dont understand what you mean. But, when i understand your last comment right, when i still like to use the classes of my framework (derived of CBaseObjectList), i have to implement some "mapper models" which i use to display and change data and transfer from view to controller and vice versa. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121420/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-ginsonic).